# Question for confirmation: Callout from Trigger using Platform Events

Tags: callout, future, after-trigger, platform-event, asynchronous

After a record is updated in Salesforce, i need to perform a callout to synchronize data to an External System.

Ideally, i would like to do this kind of synchronously, however it doesn't seem to be achievable.
I read this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&release=228&id=release-notes.rn_platform_events_publish_immediate_limit.htm) from Salesforce, where it is said that we can perform callouts after publishing Platform Event messages. However, there is a note saying: "This feature doesn't change the way you make Apex callouts from Apex triggers, which require the @future(callout=true) annotation."

My questions is more for confirmation: Is there a chance that in a Trigger i publish a platform event, and after the event is published to perform a callout to the external system? I suppose no, but i ask more for confirmation.

From my understanding, we should use @future methods, however it also needs handling concerning the Order of execution (update the record now and in 2 seconds - callouts could be performed in a different sequence, since they are asynchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Platform Event Triggers also can't make callouts, so you'd still need a Future or Queueable method. Note that asynchronous methods are still called in order of being queued, so you don't really need to worry about the "ordering problem."

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sfdcfox!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this now with `Platform Event Triggered` flows.

Once you publish a platform event. You can configure and flow to listen to this and then from the `Flow` configure it to call an Apex Action.

**NOTE** : When consuming the params in the invocalble request **DO NOT USE**  strings.get(0), as Platform events batches events raised in same time and then passes it to the Apex action. So we should iterate the input params here.

```
public without sharing class SendExternalAPIRequestPE {

    @InvocableMethod(Label='test callout' Callout=true)
    public static void fireAPIRequest(List<String> strings){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your note is confusing. Please clarify.

Comment: Modified my explanation. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: It is worth noting that this probably works because the invocable method is actually handled in a separate transaction against the org.

Comment: Yes and as transaction is separated, it makes a perfect tool to fire callouts in near real time from trigger, if Async queue is overloaded.

Comment: @PhilW The statement is not entirely true in real world example, as I am already facing the issue where sometimes it does not consider the transaction as a new one. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/376639/platform-event-flow-apex-action-behaving-incorrectly-for-sometimes

Comment: I'll be looking out for someone to answer that one!